# ASP.NET CORE WEB API: Values are null when doing HTTP Post to an endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm currently working on a **asp.net core 2 web api** project and I'm struggling with doing an HTTP Post request to my api endpoint.

I'm stuck and curious why is it that the values sent from Postman(for the request) are not binded to the model and just indicated that the values are null/empty.

Please refer to the images below.

**Postman Request**

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGuvS.png)

**Visual Studio Request**

[Visual Studio Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2dOZ.png)

Anyone also encountered this?

Comment: Do you have custom model binders in your project? Can you provide request headers?

Comment: @Merchezatter I just did the same thing I usually do with Asp.Net Web Api 2.

Here are request headers:
- Authorization: Bearer ....
- Content-type: application/json

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[FromBody]` attribute from your controller method parameter.

Also, Ensure that the properties of a Stock object is public and have the same name as the JSON object you are passing.

Comment: Its okay now. I already got it working :). Thanks for the comment.